# Python version independent string handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am fine with the string vs byte array difference.
Python3 differenciates strings and bytes, python2 is less clear. Fine.
Consider these two lines of code:

```
a=b'AAA'  #a bytes array seen from Python3, a string/bytes for python2
b='BBB'   #a string for python3, a string/bytes for python2
```

I want to write some code converting and ,here, concatenating both `a` and `b` and returning a byte/string (in python2) or bytes array(in python3).
(The expected result beeing -seen as ASCII char- AAABBB)

In other words, I want a python version agnostic line equivalent to:

```
result = a+b #returns a string/bytes in python2
```

and

```
result = a+bytes(b,'utf-8') #returns a bytes array in python3
```

I would like that line of code to run on both python 2and 3 (without change) and to avoid fancy non standard packages (struct is OK), as this may run on an embedded system.

If you wonder which encoding, my best choice would go to whatever is nearest the 8 bits extended ASCII table (256 values: I may have backslashes or European characters, but no Chinese)

The best I have found so far was:
result = a + b.encode('ASCII')

which is a problem for ASCII char >127. I tried with 'cp437', but it seems to default to ascii anyway...

Tries asked by @martineau:

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=b'aaa'
>>> b='bbbä'
>>> a+b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
>>> a+bytes(b,'latin1')
b'aaabbb\xe4'


Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=b'aaa'
>>> b='bbbä'
>>> a+b
'aaabbb\xc3\xa4'
>>> a+bytes(b,'latin1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Why not just be explicit and say `b = b'BBB'`?

Comment: Try using `b.encode('latin1')`

Comment: @martineau: with python 2:
>>> 'bbbä'.encode('latin1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

It seems my encoder is just ignored.

Comment: Please add example code to your question the reproduces the problem.

Comment: @martineau: not sure what code you want? I need to compute 'result' in a python agnostic way, b can contain extended ascii characters.. You have the code both for python2 and 3 individually above: how to write the same thing in a python agnostic way is the question. ('latin1' seems to be ignored on python2. not sure why)

Comment: I would like a short code snippet that generates the error when run in Python 2 but not 3 (or vice-versa).

Comment: @martineau:
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=b'aaa'
>>> b='bbbä'
>>> a+b
'aaabbb\xc3\xa4'
>>> a+bytes(b,'latin1')
Fails as it is not python2

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get the line feed in the comments...

Comment: Add it to your question (where it belongs).

Comment: Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=b'aaa'
>>> b='bbbä'
>>> a+b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
>>> a+bytes(b,'latin1')
b'aaabbb\xe4'

Comment: so basically: line 1,2 3 works in python 2, not python3. Lines 1,2,4 work in python 3. not 2

Comment: @martineau: I have now edited the question with the tries. Thanks for helping!

Comment: First, where are these values coming from: are they literal strings typed directly in your source code(eg, `b = 'BBB'`) or are they data from an external source (eg a file, a database, etc)? I assume the latter, but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: Second, is there some reason not to use UTF8 encoding? It is by far the most common standard when dealing with text and encoding issues, so unless you have a strong reason, that's the encoding to use. Writing your code to work correctly in Py2 and Py3 with respect to these issues is not trivial, but the way to do it is not to puzzle over which encoding to use (eg Latin1 vs Foobar); rather, it's to learn about the Unicode-Sandwich pattern and to use (or borrow some logic from) the six library.

Comment: @martineau: you have transformed b to a unicode (b=u'bbbä'). the b in my question is not. maybe that is an idea, but I cannot find a python agnostic way to go, as in my examples.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look at `six`, a Python module specifically designed to handle (some of) the differences between Python 2 and Python 3. In particular, function `ensure_binary` (see https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.ensure_binary) could solve your issue.

Notice that I understand you want to avoid depending on "fancy third-party library", but `six` is not "fancy" ;) However, I don't know what could be its overhead on an embedded system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a truly version "agnostic" way of doing it, but the following seems very close to that ideal and works in both Python 2.7.16 and 3.7.2:

```
a = b'aaa'
b = 'bbb\xc2\x84'

try:
    b = bytes(b, 'latin1')
except TypeError:
    b = bytes(b)

c = a + b

print(repr(c))  # -> 'aaabbb\xc2\x84'
```